Cannot get Django ModelForm to display neither connect custom HTML form to database
I am currently creating a Django app that is a rental apartments homepage. It is supposed to have a booking form connected to a database. However I can't get the form from forms.py to be displayed on my bookings.html page. I'd appreciate help tons as I have no idea which detail I am missing.
This is my code:
models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Booking(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_name")
    booking_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    status = (
        ('Requested', 'Requested'),
        ('Confirmed', 'Confirmed'),
        ('Cancelled', 'Cancelled'),
    )
    booking_status = models.CharField(choices=status, blank=True, null=True, default='Requested')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField()
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    phone_number = models.BigIntegerField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    booking_object = (
        ('Upper Apartment', 'Upper Apartment'),
        ('Lower Apartment', 'Lower Apartment'),
        ('Whole House', 'Whole House'),
    )
    booking_item = models.CharField(choices=booking_object)
    arrival_date = models.DateField()
    departure_date = models.DateField()
    guest_nationality = (
        ('German', 'German'),
        ('Other', 'Other'),
    )
    nationality = models.CharField(choices=guest_nationality)
    passport_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    animals = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    message = models.TextField(max_length=1000)

    class Meta:
        ordering=['last_name','first_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Booking: {self.last_name}, {self.first_name}'

forms.py
from django.forms import forms, ModelForm
from .models import Booking

class BookingForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'birth_date', 'email', 'phone_number', 'address', 'zip_code', 'city', 'country', 'booking_item', 'arrival_date', 'departure_date', 'nationality', 'passport_number', 'animals', 'message')
       

views.py
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpRequest, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect, reverse

from .models import Booking
from .forms import BookingForm

# Booking Form

def book_apartment(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = BookingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, "Thank you for booking with us. We will be in touch with you soon.")
            return redirect(main_page)
        else:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, "Please fill out all form fields.")

    form = BookingForm()
    return render(
        request,
        "{% url 'main-page' %}",
        )


booking.html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Booking</h1>

<form id="bookingForm" method="post">
    {{ form | crispy }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button id="submitButton" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}


My first approach before was to try to connect a custom html form to the database:
<h1>Booking</h1>

<form method="post" action="{{ DATABASE_URL }}" id="makeBooking">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <label for="inputFirstName">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" id="inputFirstName" name="inputFirstName" maxlength="200"
                required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <label for="inputLastName">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control" id="inputLastName" name="inputLastName" maxlength="200" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <label for="inputBirthdate">Birth Date</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="inputBirthdate" name="inputBirthdate" required>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="inputEmail">E-Mail</label>
            <input type="email" placeholder="E-Mail Address" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" maxlength="200"
                required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="inputPhoneNumber">Telephone Number</label>
            <input type="tel" placeholder="Telephone Number" class="form-control" id="inputPhoneNumber" name="inputPhoneNumber" maxlength="200"
                required>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col">
            <label for="inputAddress">Address</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Address" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" name="inputAddress" maxlength="200" required>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label for="inputZip">ZIP Code</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="ZIP Code" class="form-control" id="inputZip" name="inputZip" maxlength="200" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="inputCity">City</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="City" class="form-control" id="inputCity" name="inputCity" maxlength="200" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="inputCountry">Country</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Country" id="inputCountry" name="inputCountry" class="form-control" maxlength="200" required>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row justify-content-center">

        <div class="form-group col-8">
            <label for="inputBookingItem">You would like to book...</label>
            <select class="form-select" id="inputBookingItem" name="inputBookingItem" aria-label="Default select example" required>
                <option value="Deutsch" selected>Upper Apartment</option>
                <option value="Andere">Lower Apartment</option>
                <option value="Andere">Whole House</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label for="startDate">Arrival Date</label>
            <input id="startDate" name="startDate" class="form-control" type="date">
            <span id="startDateSelected"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label for="endDate">Departure Date</label>
            <input id="endDate" name="endDate" class="form-control" type="date">
            <span id="endDateSelected"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center row">

            <div class="form-group px-5 col">
                <label for="inputNationality">Your Nationality</label>
                <select class="form-select" id="inputNationality" name="inputNationality" aria-label="Default select example" required>
                    <option value="Deutsch" selected>German</option>
                    <option value="Andere">Other</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group px-5 col">
                <label for="inputPassportNumber">Passport Number</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Passport Number" class="form-control" id="inputPassportNumber" name="inputPassportNumber"
                    maxlength="200">
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check mt-3 ml-3 px-5 col">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkPet" name="checkPet" class="custom-control-input">
                <label for="checkPet" class="custom-control-label">
                    Pets?
                </label>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col">
            <label for="inputTextarea" class="form-label">Your Message</label>
            <textarea class="form-control resize-none" placeholder="Your Message" id="inputTextarea" name="inputTextarea" rows="5"
                maxlength="4000" required></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>

    <button type="submit" value="submit" formaction="{{ DATABASE_URL }}" formmethod="post" form="makeBooking" class="btn btn-purple border-dark">Send</button>
</form>


I would fill out the above shown form, submit, the page would reload but no entered data showed up in the database.
My other approach was to create a form through forms.py but nothing shows up on the booking.html page either.

in view you should put form = BookingForm() in a context and make it a dictionary  
and for form in html you should put action in that like this:
<form method="your method" action="{% url '#name that you put in url.py for that view you want to answer of form goes in that'%}">

Thanks for your input! I'm not exactly sure how putting form = BookingForm( ) in a context would look like, can you specify? And for the form action do I understand right it should be  {{ form | crispy }} ... {% csrf_token %} ... ?

for making it dictionary right
context = {'#any name': your variable, ...}

and in
return render() after your html page put , and then right context 

and after that your form is a dictionary and you can show it in our html page by
{{ name that you put in your dictionary }}


Ok, where to put the context variable makes sense now. I'm still not sure what content would belong within > '#any name': your variable. ... would that be "form": form?

any name its depended on you any name you can put for that but it better to put something that sense with your variable
